# found: object with keys {input} If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. what does it mean in this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to get input from an input filed and store it into a variable
but it is giving me an error following,

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {input}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

the video tutorial I am following written the same code. I have written the same code but I can't understand why my code is not running, I am a very new to react so I don't know what to do

```
function Feed() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
      setPosts(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      )
    );
  }, []);

  const sendPost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    db.collection('posts').add({
      name: 'Sumit Sarkar',
      description: 'This is a test',
      message: input,
      photoUrl: '',
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className='feed'>
      <div className='feed__inputContainer'>
        <div className='feed__input'>
          <CreateIcon />
          <form action=''>
            <input
              value={input}
              onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
              type='text'
            />
            <button onClick={sendPost} type='submit'>
              Send
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className='feed__inputOptions'>
          <InputOption Icon={ImageIcon} title='Photo' color='#70B5F9' />
          <InputOption Icon={SubscriptionsIcon} title='Video' color='#E7A33E' />
          <InputOption Icon={EventNoteIcon} title='Event' color='#C0CBCD' />
          <InputOption
            Icon={CalendarViewDayIcon}
            title='Write Article'
            color='#7FC15E'
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      {posts.map(({ id, data: { name, description, message, photoUrl } }) => (
        <Post
          key={id}
          name={name}
          description={description}
          message={message}
          photoUrl={photoUrl}
        />
      ))}

      <Post
        name='Sumit Sarkar'
        message='WOW! this works'
        description='This is a test'
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Feed;
```

Comment: That code seems to be fine so the issue is probably elsewhere. The error stack should tell which component tries to render the object.

Comment: but there is no input field or input word as key or anything

Comment: throwOnInvalidObjectType
D:/codes/Linked In clone/linkedin-clone/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13231

Comment: If you don't want to paste the whole code here, then one good way to debug it is to eliminate the possiblities. Remove pieces of rendered code until the error doesn't appear any more. Once the error doens't appear anymore, you know the last removed piece of code was the cause.